# How can I create a public-facing search with mapped results when using Wordpress as the host CMS?

Tags: wordpress, search, map

Using Drupal Views and the contributed module [CiviCRM Contact Distance Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_contact_distance_search)
I was able to create a search tool to enable unauthenticated users to find contacts and show them on a map based on proximity to a target location, and also via other exposed parameters. Drupal Views enabled me to show a name and some other data from the individual contact record and address data and org name from related org records.

The built-in proximity search function looks to be based on a profile and so won't let me mix fields from different record types.

Now I need to find a solution, or a developer who can build a solution, with Wordpress as the CMS. Has anyone created anything like this?

Answer (score 2):

The new Search Kit core-extension, combined with Form Builder (for filters, shortcode integration, etc), would be the perfect fit in all CMS integrations.

https://civicrm.org/blog/tags/searchkit

Comment: I think the proximity feature in search kit stalled - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19558. It does have the mapping feature though as of 5.37 - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19561.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look.